# How to get java object itself when its about to be collected

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

**How can we execute a piece of code using the object (its state is needed) before it gets collected if we don't have control over its source (cant enforce implementing some interface or finally block)?**

Java Reference types allow us to access an object if someone else makes it strongly reachable + if we use reference queues we can also be notified when the object is collected, unless my understanding is wrong that's all you can do with reference types, no matter what you use at any point the object is either strongly reachable or its gone and you have null.

All i really need is a way to get notified when specific object is about to be collected.

Comment: Perhaps not a dup, but [this might have useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2629180/1270789)? I think you need to modify the VM itself to do what you want to do.

Comment: Thats an overkill, at worst i could wrap an object into a proxy at runtime and override proxy finalize and hold strong ref to object, when proxy becomes finalizeable.

Comment: when proxy finalizer gets invoked, i will know i have the object and no one else is using it.

Comment: That doesn’t work. When your proxy becomes finalizable, it is no proof that the wrapped object has become unreachable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a reason why the Reference API doesn’t allow to retrieve the collected object: allowing to make a collected object reachable again, like happening with the `finalize()` method, is exactly what is not intended.

The standard approach is to create subclasses of the reference types to store the information associated with the referent, e.g. everything necessary to perform the cleanup action, within the specialized reference object. Of course, this information must not include strong references to the referent itself.

```
private static final ReferenceQueue<Integer> QUEUE = new ReferenceQueue<>();
static class IntegerPhantomReference extends PhantomReference<Integer> {
    final int value;
    public IntegerPhantomReference(Integer ref) {
        super(ref, QUEUE);
        value = ref.intValue();
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Integer[value="+value+"]";
    }
}
private static final Set<IntegerPhantomReference> REGISTERED = new HashSet<>();
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<Integer> stronglyReferenced = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Integer object = new Integer(i);
        stronglyReferenced.add(object);
        REGISTERED.add(new IntegerPhantomReference(object));
    }
    gcAndPoll("initial");
    stronglyReferenced.removeIf(i -> i%2 == 0);
    gcAndPoll("after removing even");
    stronglyReferenced.clear();
    gcAndPoll("after remove all");
    if(REGISTERED.isEmpty()) System.out.println("all objects collected");
}
private static void gcAndPoll(String msg) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.gc(); Thread.sleep(100);
    for(;;) {
        Reference<?> r = QUEUE.poll();
        if(r == null) break;
        System.out.println("collected "+r);
        REGISTERED.remove(r);
    }
}
```

```
initial
after removing even
collected Integer[value=4]
collected Integer[value=8]
collected Integer[value=6]
collected Integer[value=2]
collected Integer[value=0]
after remove all
collected Integer[value=1]
collected Integer[value=5]
collected Integer[value=3]
collected Integer[value=7]
collected Integer[value=9]
all objects collected
```

---

For completeness, there is a hack that allows to resurrect a collected object, which will stop working in Java 9.

The documentation of [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) says:

> Unlike soft and weak references, phantom references are not automatically cleared by the garbage collector as they are enqueued.

It’s not clear why this has been specified and the [`get()` method of `PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html#get--) has been overridden to always return `null`, exactly to disallow taking any benefit from the fact that this reference has not been cleared. Since the purpose of this special behavior is unclear, it has been removed from the specification in Java 9 and these references are automatically cleared like any other.

But for previous versions, it is possible to use Reflection with access override to access the referent, to do exactly what the API was not intended to allow. Needless to say, that’s just for informational purpose and is strongly discouraged (and as said, it stops working in Java 9).

```
private static final ReferenceQueue<Integer> QUEUE = new ReferenceQueue<>();
private static final Set<PhantomReference<Integer>> REGISTERED = new HashSet<>();
public static void main(String[] args)
        throws InterruptedException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<Integer> stronglyReferenced = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Integer object = new Integer(i);
        stronglyReferenced.add(object);
        REGISTERED.add(new PhantomReference<>(object, QUEUE));
    }
    gcAndPoll("initial");
    stronglyReferenced.removeIf(i -> i%2 == 0);
    gcAndPoll("after removing even");
    stronglyReferenced.clear();
    gcAndPoll("after remove all");
    if(REGISTERED.isEmpty()) System.out.println("all objects collected");
}
static final Field REFERENT;
static {
    try {
        REFERENT = Reference.class.getDeclaredField("referent");
        REFERENT.setAccessible(true);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
private static void gcAndPoll(String msg)
        throws InterruptedException, IllegalAccessException {
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.gc();
    Thread.sleep(100);
    for(;;) {
        Reference<?> r = QUEUE.poll();
        if(r == null) break;
        Object o = REFERENT.get(r);
        System.out.println("collected (and now resurrected)"+o);
        REGISTERED.remove(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: just another example of shitty api created by jdk devs, instead of giving you clear way to say "hey jvm when this object is about to be cleared let me do some work" they give you crappy finalize... annoying

Comment: In Java 9, there is an API to say exactly that, [“execute this `Runnable` when that object is dead”](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Cleaner.html#register-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Runnable-). When you replace the `int` value in my first code example with a `Runnable` reference and add a thread polling the queue and executing them, you get the same (and that’s exactly how it has been implemented).

Comment: @Holger what a beauty of code! It would take forever to understand it in exact glory details, I admit, but I do have a question about `Cleaner` if you don't mind. I assume that when the documentation says *when the object becomes phantom reachable*, this implies that it is now available for garbage collection? Even if you theoretically hold a strong reference to that phantom reference? I understand that `get` will always return null...

Comment: @Eugene being *phantom reachable* implies that someone has a strong reference to a `PhantomReference` pointing to the object (the cleaner will have too). Otherwise, the object is *unreachable*.

Comment: @Eugene that’s the reason why the code of this answer stores all `PhantomReference` instances into the `REGISTERED` set; they must kept reachable as otherwise, they get collected like ordinary objects and nothing will happen. They are only enqueued when reachable (that applies to all types of reference objects).

Comment: @Holger cannot agree, using this approach you need to capture the state and create the runnable and keep it in reference, what if you object keeps changing that state? maybe you need to read it at the last moment. If those people knew how to create good apis we wouldnt have to even know what is PhantomReference...

Comment: @vach 99.9% of all developers never need a `PhantomReference` in their life. Your idea of accessing the object that is supposed to be unreachable (which normally implies being *inaccessible*), is exactly what the “crappy finalize” is about. A contradiction in itself. You may blame “those people”, saying things like “If those people knew how to create good apis…”, but as far as I can see, the C#/.NET developers failed on this issue too and I don’t know of any better example. I also have my doubt that you are the one who could propose a better alternative.